# How to UnitTest asynchronous calls to delegate methods in Swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, asynchronous, delegates, xctest

I have the following class with a static method that uses MKDirections to calculate custom routes between two coordinates. Once it finishes calculating, the method uses a delegate to pass the route (an MKPolyline object) to the View Controller which adds it to a MapView as an overlay. Every route is assigned a title that determines in which color the route is rendered on the map.

```
class NavigationInterface {

    weak static var routeDelegate: RouteDelegate!



    static func addRouteFromTo(sourceCoor: CLLocationCoordinate2D, destinationCoor: CLLocationCoordinate2D, transportTypeString: String)
{
    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceCoor)
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoor)
    //var route = MKRoute()
    let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false

    //get MKDirectionsTransportType based on String identifier
    request.transportType = getTransportType(transportTypeString: transportTypeString)

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)


    directions.calculate { (response, error) in
        if let directionResponse = response?.routes.first {
            let route = directionResponse.polyline
            route.title = transportTypeString
            print("Got Here")

            self.routeDelegate!.didAddRoute(route: route) 
        }
    }
}
```

The delegate is defined through the following protocol:

```
protocol RouteDelegate: class {

    func didAddRoute(route: MKPolyline)
    func didAddBoundary(boundary: MKPolygon)

}
```

The View Controller implements the delegate as follows:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NavigationInterface.routeDelegate = self
   }


extension MapViewController: RouteDelegate {


    // delegate Method
    // called in Navigation Interface
    func didAddRoute(route: MKPolyline) {
        mapView.add(route)
    }

    func didAddBoundary(boundary: MKPolygon) {
        mapView.add(boundary)
    }
}
```

Now I have attempted to write a UnitTest which checks whether the delegate method "didAddRoute" returns the correct route

For this purpose I've created a test class "NavigationTests" which implements the RouteDelegate protocol and an test method that calculates a route and then evaluates the route returned from the "NavigationTests" protocol implementation of "didAddRoute":

```
class NavigationTests: XCTestCase, RouteDelegate {



    var routes = [MKPolyline]()
    var asyncExpectation: XCTestExpectation?

    func didAddRoute(route: MKPolyline) {
        routes.append(route)
        asyncExpectation?.fulfill()

    }
    ...


    func testaddRouteFromTo(){


    NavigationInterface.routeDelegate = self
    asyncExpectation = expectation(description: "routes returned from delegate method")

    NavigationInterface.addRouteFromTo(sourceCoor: CoordinateA, destinationCoor: CoordinateB, transportTypeString: "roadTravel")

        let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [self.asyncExpectation!], timeout: 2.0)
        if result == XCTWaiter.Result.completed {

            let route = self.routes.first
            XCTAssert(route!.title == "roadTravel", "failed to retrieve correct route")
            print(route!.title)

        } else {
            XCTFail()
        }
    }

}
```

Now this test method randomly returns routes from the MapViewController implementation of RouteDelegate instead of the NavigationTests implementation. W

How can I avoid these unwanted references to the MapViewController and why is it created at all since I do not instantiate it in the test? 
Ideally I would like to prevent the MapViewController from being instantiated when running this test class since it is not required for the Unit Test.

How can I make sure that only the NavigationTests implementation of the RouteDelegate is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Statics vs. tests

Because `addRouteFromTo(sourceCoor:destinationCoor:transportTypeString:)` is a static method, you have made `NavigationInterface.routeDelegate` static as well. When your tests run, they are setting a global variable. This means the tests have side effects which last beyond the scope of the tests.

Here are a couple of approaches to prevent this from happening:

a) Create a `setUp()` and `tearDown()`. In `setUp()`, save the old value of `NavigationInterface.routeDelegate` before overwriting it to `self`. In `tearDown()`, restore the old value.

b) Change from statics to an object. As a general rule, statics make things harder to test.

Prefer b). It is safer, and lets the pressure of testability improve your design.

*…I don't see any references to MapViewController in your test. Was it created by your application delegate?*

## How to test an asynchronous call?

Now to your larger question. A test that does actual networking is slow and fragile. It depends on your network conditions. It depends on the back end. It introduces a time lag.

You would be better served by restructuring your code so that you can test the following:

- Are you creating the correct MKDirectionsRequest?
- Are you handling the response correctly?

This will be expressed in at least 2 tests, but probably more. Once you can independently test response handling, then you can test errors as well as successful responses.

So how do you test "create the response" independently from "handle the response"? By doing this work in separate methods. The tests can then just call these methods.

There is no need to test that Apple makes a network call, or does something on the back end, or sends a response. If you follow this approach, the need for asynchronous tests drops dramatically.

*I hope this helps. If you need clarification, please ask. For more thoughts on how "the way Apple shows us to write code isn't good testable design," see https://qualitycoding.org/design-sense/*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I refactored my Code to make the Interface methods non-static. In the test I instantiate a new NavigationInterface object and now the tests run fine. I originally made the methods static for simplicity. There are some custom navigation classes that are essentially hidden behind the NavigationInterface. The only way the MapViewController should interact with them is via the NavigationInterface class, which doesn’t have any instance variables except for the RouteDelegate.

Comment: Since the MapViewController is the only instance of RouteDelegate that is ever created in the production code, I thought it wouldn’t matter. I thought I could run the test independently from the App so I did not instantiate the MapViewController at all. That's why you are not seeing any references to it in the test. But since the tests require some host application APIs, I had to include the host App as testing target which means that with every test the Simulator will boot up and run the entire app.

Comment: That's what I thought. Using the host app as-is allows it to run outside of test control, which is bad for testing. I recommend using a different app delegate for tests: https://qualitycoding.org/ios-app-delegate-testing/